# Php array related query

Tags: php

I have an array result like this

```
 Array
 (
 [0] => Array
    (
        [timesheetcode] => 66697227755915329598
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [timesheetcode] => 74834566212594198885
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [timesheetcode] => 74834566212594198885
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [timesheetcode] => 74834566212594198885
    )
 )
```

I want to break this array like this

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [timesheetcode] => 66697227755915329598
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [timesheetcode] => 74834566212594198885
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [timesheetcode] => 74834566212594198885
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [timesheetcode] => 74834566212594198885
            )
    )
)
```

Actually, if timesheetcode value is the same then create another array in the existing array. Can anyone please help me how can I do this?

Comment: Do show us what you've tried, your best attempt (code) and where you're stuck. What error message(s) do you get?

Comment: You need a simple _control break_ implementation for this. Input data needs to be properly sorted by timesheetcode, and then you just loop over it, and compare the current timesheetcode, with that from the previous loop iteration. Whether you use a temporary array to gather elements first and then add that to your result array, or work with a counter variable – up to you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I did it before thread closed!
Your home work is done, good luck in the interview :)

Code

```php
$a = [
 [ "timesheetcode" => "66697227755915329598"],
 [ "timesheetcode" => "74834566212594198885"],
 [ "timesheetcode" => "74834566212594198885"],
 [ "timesheetcode" => "74834566212594198885"],
];

$b = [];

foreach ($a as $line) {

    if (!array_key_exists($line["timesheetcode"],$b))
    {
      $b[$line["timesheetcode"]] = [];
    }

    array_push($b[$line["timesheetcode"]],$line);
}

$b = array_values($b);

foreach ($b as $key => $line) {
    if (sizeof($line) === 1) {
        $b[$key] = $line[0];
    }
}

print_r($b);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [timesheetcode] => 66697227755915329598
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [timesheetcode] => 74834566212594198885
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [timesheetcode] => 74834566212594198885
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [timesheetcode] => 74834566212594198885
                )

        )

)
```